# Using a transformation to obtain the pdf for a quotient of two standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I want to find the pdf of $U=\frac{X}{Y}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are distributed as standard normal random variables.

I want to do this using a transformation method from $(X,Y)$ to $(U, V)$. I obtaining a one-to-one transformation between $(X,Y)$ to $(U, V)$ with $U=\frac{X}{Y}$ and $V=X$, and vice versa (via the inverses, let these be $X = h_{1} (U,V) = V,\ Y=h_2(U,V)= \frac{V}{U}$ ).

Then we can apply the following:

$f_{UV}(u,v) = f_{XY} (h_{1} (u,v),\ h_2(u,v)) |\det{J}|$, where $J$ is the Jacobian of the transformation.

Then to find the pdf of the quotient I can take the marginal of $U$.

My original transformation from $(X,Y)$ to $(U,V)$ was: $U=\frac{X}{Y}$ and $V=X$, however I didn't get the desired result (of a Cauchy pdf) and after looking online I have seen that others have got the desired result with using $V=Y$.

In both cases $|\det{J}|$ is the same, but obviously the transformation inverses give different results, producing a different end answer. My question is: why does my transformation not work?

Answer (score 1):

> In both cases $\lvert \det J\rvert$ is the same, ...

They are quite different transformations.   Why would you even anticipate they have the same Jacobian determinant?

---

When $U=XY^{-1}, V=X$, then $X=V, Y=U^{-1}V$

$\begin{align}f_{U,V}(u,v) &= f_{X,Y}(v, u^{-1}v)\cdotp\begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial (v, u^{-1}v)}{\partial (u,v)}\end{Vmatrix} \\[1ex] & = f_{X,Y}(v, u^{-1}v)\cdotp\begin{Vmatrix}0 & 1\\-u^{-2}v & u^{-1}\end{Vmatrix} \\[1ex] & = \color{blue}{\lvert u^{-2}v\rvert} f_{X,Y}(v, u^{-1}v)\\[3ex] f_U(u) &= { u^{-2} }\int_\Bbb R \lvert v\rvert f_{X,Y}(v,u^{-1}v)\operatorname d v \end{align}$

---

When $U=XY^{-1}, W=Y$, then $X=UW, Y=W$

$\begin{align}f_{U,W}(u,w) &= f_{X,Y}(uw, w)\cdotp\begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial (uw, w)}{\partial (u,w)}\end{Vmatrix} \\[1ex] & = f_{X,Y}(uw, w)\cdotp\begin{Vmatrix}w & u\\0 & 1\end{Vmatrix} \\[1ex] & = \color{blue}{\lvert w\rvert} f_{X,Y}(uw, w)\\[3ex] f_U(u)&= \int_\Bbb R \lvert w\rvert f_{X,Y}(uw,w)\operatorname d w \end{align}$

Comment: I didn't anticipate that, hence why I calculated and obviously got it wrong - part of learning in Mathematics is making mistakes, including during simple calculations. Thank you for your response.